# Transformer secondary coil impedance

Tags: transceiver, rf-power, impedance, electronics

To transfer maximum power from the secondary coil to the load, I need to find secondary coil impedance. My load impedance 5 - J365. I would design a matching circuit between load and secondary coil, if I know secondary coil transformer source impedance.

Can anyone please share your thoughts?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Perhaps related? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/80929/reflecting-impedance-in-a-transformer

Comment: My load impedance 5 - J365. I would design a matching circute between load and secondary coil, if I know secondary coil transformer source impedance. Any idea on how to calculate it?

Comment: I considered just answering 'yes' but ended up just marking to close as "not clear what you're asking" instead

Comment: Real world, measure it.